# How to filter a dynamic block column view by tags with a :match selector?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags, column, filtering

I'm trying to filter an org mode heading by tag in a dynamic block, but the match syntax is not quite working out.

Example:

```
#+COLUMNS: %25ITEM %TAGS

* Something                                                       :work:home:
* Other thing                                                          :home:


#+BEGIN: columnview :id global :match "TAGS=\"work\""
| ITEM        | TAGS        |
|-------------+-------------|
| Something   | :work:home: |
| Other thing | :home:      |
#+END: columnview
```

The `:match "TAGS=\"work\""` query returns all headings. How to fix the query so only the headings tagged with `work` are displayed in the dynamic block?

Comment: same problem; any progress/info?

Comment: @user2583621 nope, I could not figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Try `:match "work"`. IIRC, match already takes care of the `"TAGS=\"` stuff.

Comment: Nope, it produces the same result (both headings are returned).

Comment: OK, I'm not an expert, but I have this working on my machine. I have removed `columnview` from my #+END: form though, so it just reads `#+END:`. That, in conjunction with `:match "work" are the only differences between my test file and what you've posted in the OP. Did that help?

Comment: Nope, still does not work for me with the given example. Both headings are listed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using org-mode 9.0.1. After updating to 9.3.7, it works like a charm. Comparing source code of org-colview.el, it showed that my org-mode version didn't have the match argument. Maybe updating would solve your issue as well? (It seems to me your query syntax is correct.)

Answer (score 0):

As [Paul van Geber said](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/60012/24054), there was an update to Org-mode that seems to have resolved this issue. I just had to make a slight change in the way my match query was being made.

If I want just the items tagged `work`, I have to do:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :id global :match "work"
```

... and then run `org-update-all-blocks`.

If I use `TAGS=`, I have to match all tags, apparently. For instance, to match the first item in my original example, I need to do:

```
#+BEGIN: columnview :id global :match "TAGS=\":work:home:\""
```

... and again `org-update-all-dblocks`.